# How To Restrict Access To Some Report Tiles On A Power BI Dashboard

Tags: report, powerbi, dashboard

Scenario:  I have approximately 30 reports I need to share with users.  I want to build a dashboard of tiles for these reports so that the dashboard link can be shared but only some users will have access to some reports on the dashboard.  i.e. not all report tiles will show for every user.

How can I give only some users access to some report tiles on a Power BI dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to select objects on a dashboard in a workspace and restrict them to specific users as such. 
The best way to do this is to use a [App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-apps) based on a workspace. You can then select the dashboards, reports and datasets that are in that workspace and deploy them to specific people. You will have to create variations of the dashboards, with the relevant tiles in them and include the reports, if you want then the drill down from the tile to the report.

You can set things as auto-deploy the App to people, and Apps allow you to update/delete the objects in them.

Hope that helps

Comment: Can I restrict access per person automatically? That is, a person can see ONLY his own result in the dashboard in the Power BI app (= page filtered to him). He must not be able to see other people's results.

Comment: Yes you can, with Row Level Security https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

Comment: Yep, basically using: username() or userprincipalname() DAX function